# Get IllegalArgumentException when invoking method from java agent

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to call a class method from a java agent, but I keep getting a `IllegalArgumentException` error.

This is my code:

```
Class cls = Class.forName("class"); 

Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("stringMethod", String.class); 

method.invoke(cls, "example string");
```

And this is the error I get:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class`

I'm able to get the class and the method, but invoking the method causes the error. Does anyone know what's causing this or how I can fix it?

Comment: Which line? Please show the entire error message

Comment: The last line, where I invoke the method

Comment: Unless `"class"`  (which is an illegal class name, as `class` is a keyword) is `java.lang.Class` or it's supertypes this IAE is expected. you should pass an **instance** of that type into `Method.invoke` as first argument - or `null` if the method is `static`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Sorry, can you explain how to get an instance of the class?

Comment: The first argument to mthod.invoke() should be the instance of cls.

Comment: As always: Call a constructor - either directly or through reflection.